# If $L\sim\mathrm{Gamma}(n,p)$, then $L^2\sim\;$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Suppose we have the random variable $L= \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$, with $N\sim\mathrm{Pois}(p_1)$ and $X_i\sim\mathrm{Exp}(p_2)$.

Does that mean that $L\sim\mathrm{Gamma}(n,p_2)$ as the sum of exponential random variables? What would be the distribution of $L^2$?

Many thanks

Comment: Given $N=n$ and the exponential RVs $X_i$ are IID then $L\sim \Gamma(n,p_2)$, yes but the unconditional distribution is not necessarily so since it is a random sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditioned on $\{N=n\}$, $n\in\mathbb Z\cap[1,\infty)$ we have that
$$
L = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim\Gamma(n,p_2).
$$
So the distribution of $L$ is given by
\begin{align}
f_L(t) &= \mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(t)\mathbb P(N=0) +\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{L\mid N=n}(t\mid n) f_N(n)\\
&= e^{-p_1}\mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(t)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p_2(p_2t)^{n-1}e^{-p_2t}}{(n-1)!} e^{-p_1}\frac{p_1^n}{n!}\\
&= e^{-p_1}\mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(t) + \frac{\sqrt{p_1} \sqrt{p_2} e^{-p_2 t-p_1} I_1\left(2 \sqrt{t} \sqrt{p_1} \sqrt{p_2}\right)}{\sqrt{t}},
\end{align}
where $I_1(t)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind satisfying the differential equation $t^2y'' + ty' - (t^2+1)y = 0$. In principle we could compute
$$
\mathbb P(L^2\leqslant t) = \mathbb P(L\leqslant \sqrt t) = e^{-p_1}\mathsf 1_{[0,\infty)}(t) + \int_0^{\sqrt t} f_L(s)\ \mathsf ds
$$
to find the distribution of $L^2$, but this integral is unlikely to have a nice closed form.